# Can we count an if result and change the resulting text?

Tags: advanced-conditionals, reverse-related-entries

I'd like to be able to use an if statement to determine what to show based on the amount of results from the if statement in a reverse related entry.

For example:

If an actor has two stage names, list the two stage names using the EE loop. But if the stage name fields in the entries match the actors name , show the 'No other stage names' text and not list the actors name again as I'm using it elsewhere on the page. 
I am trying the code below, but not working...

```
    {reverse_related_entries channel="play"}
                            {if stage_name != actor_name OR if stage_name !="" }
                            {stage_name}
                            {if count <1}
                            No other stage names
                            {/if}
                            {/if}
                        {/reverse_related_entries}
```

Any ideas??

Thx!

Comment: I don't think it can be done with the reverse_related_entries tag. Maybe try the Playa addon? THen you can use something like {exp:playa:children search:stage_name="=not {actor_name}"}

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the {if no_reverse_related_entries} conditional [mentioned in the user guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#reverse-related-entries-tag-pair)? You also seem to have a typo in your conditionals.

Can you try this and see if it works

```
{reverse_related_entries channel="play"}
    {if stage_name != actor_name OR stage_name != ""}
        {stage_name}
    {/if}

    {if no_reverse_related_entries}
        No other stage names
    {/if}
{/reverse_related_entries}
```

Comment: Hi Jerome,thanks for a quick reply. I tried that code, but the hang up is there are entries with no stage name, so the no other stage names doesn't get called.  For example, I have 6 entries for an actor, and 3 of those entries have a stage name and the other 3 are blank. I want to show the the 3 stage names, and if no stage names different then the model name show the no results found tag

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not really understand what you are after here. You can use the {if no_reverse_related_entries} inside a lot of conditional combinations, whichever one suits your specific needs.